# Non-member-function form for insertion operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I want to have a non-class member overloaded put operator which uses reference parameters to output the information from a car object.

Here is my code:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Car& p)
{
         os << "For a car make " << p.get_make() << ", " << p.get_year()<< ", the price is $" << p.get_price()  << endl;
         return os;
}
```

I get a  `std::ostream& Car::operator<<(std::ostream&, Car&)' must take exactly one argument` error

Am I not allowed to have a Car as a parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: just declare the function as friend to the class.(i.e to Car class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you wanted to define a *non-member* operator. Yet you placed your operator definition inside class definition, which made the compiler to treat it as *member* (member implementation of this operator must have only one parameter, hence the error message). If you want to define a non-member operator, either move it outside of class definition or declare it as `friend` (or both)

Comment: What's the relation between the ostream-member insertion operator and its non-member overload? When I write "std::cout << car", which one gets called?

Comment: @h9uest: What member are you talking about? `ostream` does not have a member operator for `Car` type. `ostream` is a standard library class. It knows nothing about user-defined `Car` type and can't possibly have any overload for it.

Comment: Hi AnT, I formulated the question better here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306185/relation-between-ostream-insertion-operator-and-its-non-member-overload