# Relation between ostream insertion operator and its non-member overload

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, operator-overloading, std

```
int i=0;
std::cout << i;
```

1, The non-member overload(two arguments, one being ostream& the other being type of operand, say int) is defined in std namespace. So if `using namespace std;` is not present, there's no way I see that the non-member overload can be called.

2, If instead, the member operator(member of ostream; one argument, being the type of operand, say int) function << of ostream is called, I'd expect something like: `std::cout.operator<< i;` --- isn't this rediculous?

So, what on earth is the relation between the two?

Question extended: if I want to overload the insertion operator so that `std::cout << my_obj;` works(assume my_obj is the instance of a user-defined type, MyType), should I do

a) `ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, MyType obj);` in the namespace of MyType

or

b) in MyType:

```
class MyType
{
 ...
   ostream& operator<< (MyType);
};
```

does option b) ever work? Does it even make sense(I remember seeing it somewhere ...)? What's the relation between option a) & b)?

---

**EDIT MAR 27**

Upon the request from ecatmur, here're two overloads that have the same signature but in different namespaces. Using gcc 4.9.2: http://melpon.org/wandbox/

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class MyType
    {};

    // signature can be found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, char ch)
    {
        out << "std is doomed\n";
        return out;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, MyType t)
    {
        out << "std is super doomed\n";
        return out;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyNameSpace::MyType t;
    std::cout << t; // ... super doomed; ADL is working as intended.
    std::cout << 't'; // t; this proves that when there're two operator overloads with the same signature but in different namespaces, there're no compilation errors. gcc defaults to the std one.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the first point(using namespace std; is not present), theoretically, the non-member overload should be called this way: std::cout std::<< i; --- clearly this doesn't make sense - but the more I think about the syntax, the more I think it should be called this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-member overloads you're thinking of are [those for character data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) and [those for `std::string` etc.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt); they're available via [*argument-dependent lookup*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).  You can indeed write `std::cout.operator<<(i)` for [types where `ostream` has a member `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

For your own types you're thinking of a (non-member) `friend operator<<`, which can be particularly useful for template classes (the [Barton-Nackman trick](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Barton-Nackman_trick)) or for those where the `operator<<` accesses data not available via accessors:

```
class MyType
{
 ...
   friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, MyType obj) { ... }
};
```

Your proposed signature would allow you to write `my_obj << my_obj`, which is unlikely to make much sense.

Comment: Hi ecatmur. Thanks for the quick reply - especially for pointing out std::cout.operator<<(i) for supported types. So are you saying, the ostream member operator is called WHEN AND ONLY WHEN we call the insertion operator in this awkward way? when we do std::cout << i, it's actually the non-member overload in std that gets called? If that's the case, don't we need to specify it's the non-member overload defined in namespace std by something like std::cout std::operator<< i?

Comment: Also, for the extended question, in order to make MyType work with cout, is this the only option? Would my proposed option b) ever have a chance working?(My proposed signature will not allow my_obj << my_obj; the return type is ostream&)

Comment: @h9uest no, that's not what I'm saying at all. Standard operator syntax can call either a non-member or member operator overload.

Comment: @h9uest the return type of an operator gives the type of the result, not of the arguments.

Comment: How come? The more I think about it, the more suspicious it is. So I looked into <iostream>, or rather, <ostream>, and found all the overloads of operator << were defined in namespace std. That being said, if you don't have "using namespace std", the compiler shouldn't know what you're talking about by "<<"; I tried this: std::operator<<(std::cout, "hi"); which works.

Comment: So, why on earth does "std::cout << 2" work? The compiler shouldn't be able to know what you are referring to by "<<"; std::operator<<(std::cout, "hi") clearly tells it what you mean.

Comment: @h9uest argument-dependent lookup; see above. For operators and free functions, namespaces of arguments are considered in lookup. `std::cout` is of a type within namespace `std`.

Comment: std::cout being the first argument is not confusing at all. The key thing to the question is, to uniquely identify the operator, the prefix std:: before << is critical. So "<<" by itself is nothing. std::operator<< is something.

Comment: Your argument is correct only if C++ compiler automatically transforms "<<" to "std::operator<<", but it opens a can of worms. What if by "<<" I actually refer to the << operator with the same signature in my own namespace?

Comment: @h9uest if you have two operators with the same arguments in different namespaces, and both are found by argument dependent lookup or otherwise, you will have an ambiguity and your code will not compile. Try it with a compliant compiler eg recent clang or gcc.

Comment: Hi ecatmur. I've edited the question and included the results by gcc 4.9.2. The compiler did not give an ambiguity error but defaulted to the std overload. So basically, it maps "<<" to "std::operator<<". I've got some interesting outputs from objdump of the .o file confirming this, which I'll post back tmr morning. So given the reality, if I want to call the overload in MyNameSpace, what's the concise and natural way to call it? (I know MyNameSpace::operator<<(...) works, but it's awkward. Also, using namespace MyNameSpace; does not count. It's cheating :p )

Comment: @h9uest neither (the type of) std::cout nor char are in namespace MyNameSpace so there's no reason for ambiguity to occur.

Comment: Can you please point me to  the section in the standard or whatever doc on the web regarding the specific rule for adl(namely, the arguments need to be defined in the same namespace as the operator/function itself in order to be correctly found by adl). Also, if I want to call the operator overload (with std::cout and char) defined in my own namespace, how do I do it?

Comment: @h9uest the relevant section is basic.lookup.argdep. If you want an operator defined in your own namespace to be called via unqualified lookup, you would have to firstly make it available either through `using namespace` or enclosure, and secondly ensure that the overload in std is not visible, probably through `<iosfwd>`.